# HDFS Balancer is balancing blocks in the same rack of nodes

Tags: hdfs

When am running HDFS balancer using below command , the balancer is balancing the blocks in the same rack, and it is not moving blocks to different racks, where nodes are having free space.

is there any property to set to copy the blocks across multiple racks? i am using HDFS FEDERATION in the cluster.

Comment: Hi Hari, it looks to me that you didn't copy the command used.

Comment: @Tudor - i have used below command. <hadoop-home>/sbin/start-balancer.sh -include -f hosts.txt -threshold 10